# Get-WmiObject Win32_Product critical error

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, wmi, uninstallation

I have created a remote uninstaller, it has been working perfectly until I got to a pc which has too many MSI packages. Until the Get-WmiObject Win32_Product can finish searching and listing all the packages it gets a critical error with no explanation.
My guess is that it has a timeout timer but I have no idea how to modify it or if it is even possible.

the code I use :

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the computer name' # the name of the computer to remove the app from

Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -Property Name | Out-GridView -Title "All apps on destination Computer"

$Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input name of the application (has to be exact name)'  #name of the application
$Application = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Name}  #choose the object, this will be the app that we will delete
if ($Application) {
  $Application.Uninstall()
  "The removal was successful"
}
else {
  $Name + ' is not installed on ' + $ComputerName
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

the error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Critical error 
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Obje ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

the application asks the name of the computer that I want to uninstall an app form, lists all the packages in that computer, and I choose the one I want to delete, copy the name and paste it in the next field.

this error happens after I enter a name of the computer, also it takes a really long time to load, the error happens at 55 second mark from the moment it starts listing.

My idea is that the command has a timeout or a number of max

If anyone has any idea why I get this error or how to avoid it please help

Comment: what is in $name and in $computername? you may try to put single quotes around the computername an re-try, I did face this issue some years ago where the computername contained special chars. also would have some optimizations to the current code to speed things a bit up etc. but first lets take care of the Critical error

Comment: the name is the name that I will choose after the query, while the computer name is standard so I know it's not the issue

Comment: the query works without any issues if you run it locally on that machine?

Comment: I haven't tried tbh, client's machine so I have no hand on it. But I haven't seen much of a difference between runing the command locally or remotely

Comment: Why would you do `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName` twice? You could store the result in the first part in a variable, then select property name from that and and show the GridView. BTW. Did you know `Out-GridView` also has a parameter called `-PassThru` ? If you set that, the user can select the name directly from there. No need for the second Read-Host

Comment: that's an upgrade I have in more detailed code, this is the core of the code.

Comment: I don't know if the people that view this question are here to potentially answer or they have same question as I do